# Javascript onclick with img is not working on IE10 with HTML 5 enable

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We have a legacy HTML+JavaScript code which has been written approx 15 years back. We are enabling some of the feature in the code by using HTML5 like as search box etc.

While enabling HTML-5, checkbox stop working on IE-10, same code is working on Firefox and chrome. Checkbox functionality has been implemented using  tag.

Below is the snapshot of the code.

```
function ClickCheckBoxImage (object)
{ 
  if( !IsDisabled (object))
  {
    SetCheckBoxImage (object, !IsChecked (object))
    eval (object.getAttribute ("onchange")) 
  }
}

Page.prototype.AddCheckBox = function (name, value, onChange,
  forceNavUpdate, rebootOnChange, isReadOnly, condition)
{
  var checkBox
  var checkBoxHelper
  var checked = value.toLowerCase() == "true"
  var newElement = document.createDocumentFragment()
  var checkBoxName = name + "checkbox"
  onChange = (!onChange) ? "" : onChange + ";"

  if (isReadOnly == null) isReadOnly = false 
  if(userNameglobal == 4) isReadOnly = true
  onClick = "ClickCheckBoxImage(this);"
  onChange += 'UpdateDependentRows (document.getElementById(\''+name+'\'));' 
  if (this.autoSubmit) onChange += 'SubmitOnChangeOf (\''+checkBoxName+'\');'

  if (forceNavUpdate) onClick += 'UpdateNavReloadCB(this);'
  // Create the checkbox Image
  checkBox = CreateElement ('<img class="checkbox" '+ 
    ' name="'+checkBoxName+'" id="'+checkBoxName+'" onclick="'+onClick+'">')
  checkBox.setAttribute ("onchange", onChange)
  checkBox.setAttribute ("disabled", isReadOnly)
  checkBox.setAttribute ("helper", name)
  SetImageValue (checkBox, checked)
  checkBox.src = GetCheckBoxImageName (checkBox)
  this.SetCommonAttributes (checkBox, rebootOnChange, condition);
  newElement.appendChild (checkBox);
  // Create the helper
  checkBoxHelper = CreateElement ('<input type="hidden" id="'+name+
    '" name="'+name+'" value="'+value+'">');
  this.SetCommonAttributes (checkBoxHelper, rebootOnChange, condition);
  newElement.appendChild (checkBoxHelper);
  return newElement;
}
```

Function ClickCheckBoxImage() has been set to onclick. While debugging the issue, It has been seen that ClickCheckBoxImage() is not calling in case of IE-10, but it is calling in case firefox and chrome.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very weird way to make this. However, you are overriding the onclick in the `forceNavUpdate`, and you don't share the `ClickCheckBoxImage()` code. My suggestion is to make in pure CSS, with IE9+ and all other browsers will run ok and you don't need nothing of code.

Comment: Hi Marcos,

I have shared code of ClickCheckBoxImage(). This function is define din the first line only. This is the legacy code, we can't change it completely. So, I am looking for the way in which minimal change is required.

Regards,